# Vim mksession takes variables as literals

Tags: vim

I have a function in VIM that calls mksession. I wanted to make it use a function argument, but it takes the variable as literal:

```
func! MakeFullSession(name)
   execute mksession! a:name
   [...]
```

The session is saved to a file called "a:name". Can I change that behaviour? The best would even be with a prepended directory:

```
~/.vim/sessions/.a:name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to put everything to be executed in quotes, then concatenate the value of `a:name`.  Try this:

```
execute "mksession! " . a:name
```